# Is there a generic regex for finding IP on any OS?

Tags: python, regex, ip, cross-platform

```
/sbin/ifconfig $(/sbin/route | awk '/default/ {print $8}') | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I have the regex above which will work on CentOS, Kubuntu and even probably Red Hat but this wont work on Mac. Is there a generic one that would work on any OS?

Comment: Why doesn't it work on Mac? What is the difference in output?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Well, for one thing, BSD and SysV `route` with no arguments is an error; you can use `route get default`, but even then, the output of `route` isn't standardized; on *BSD systems you'll need to `awk '/interface:/ {print $2}'` or similar, but that won't work on linux or SysV systems. (And of course none of this will come even close to working on Windows…)

Comment: @user2921139: Please include more information, like what abarnert mentioned, in your question next time.

Comment: Since you included Python in your original tags, would you be happy with a Python solution?

Comment: Any OS?  You mean any Unix or Linux OS?  `/sbin/ifconfig` is certainly not going to work on Windows (or AmigaOS). :)

Comment: It's not even going to work on every Unix, because neither `route` nor `ifconfig` is part of POSIX or any other ubiquitous standard. For that matter, I don't think the default shell isn't required to handle `$(…)` (although using backticks would solve that part).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a regex, and has nothing to do with python. It will obviously work on these linux distros.

in stead of using 
`/sbin/route` use `netstat -r` for it to work on both mac and linux

Comment: That still has a lot of problems. First, which column from `netstat -r` do you want? And, once you get the interface, how do you parse the output of `ifconfig`? And, for both commands, how do you specify the default protocol (between IPv4 and IPv6) instead of hardcoding one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on *any* OS, of course that isn't possible. Not a single one of the four programs you're running even exists on, say, Windows. Nor does either `cmd` or `PowerShell` have the `$(…)` syntax of `bash`.

---

A much better—although still not perfect—solution is to call `getaddrinfo`, in C or Python or whatever language you prefer. For example:

```
python -c 'import socket; print socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None)[0][4][0]'
```

This has the advantage of working on every platform with Python and sockets (including Windows).

It has the disadvantage of relying on name lookup. For example, just add an entry to `/etc/hosts` mapping your hostname to some other address, and you'll get back that other address rather than your own… But there is no cross-platform solution that avoids those problems.

---

If you wanted something close-ish to what you started with, that avoids the name lookup problems, and that works on a lot of popular modern POSIX systems (but obviously still not, say, Windows), you might be able to get part-way there.

First:

```
iface=$(netstat -rl -f inet | awk '/^default/ {print $7)')
```

You might notice a couple problems here. First, `netstat` doesn't specify the number or order of columns; passing `-l` should get you at least 8 of them, and `Netif` will often be the 7th, but don't blame me if some platform I haven't tested has `Mtu` there, and therefore you get an interface named `1500`. Second, notice that I had to specify IPv4 (via `-f inet`), unlike `route`, where you can ask for the default protocol. Even in late 2014, that's already wrong for 5% of users, and that number is (hopefully) only going to increase.

But the big problem is what to do with this once you get it. `ifconfig en0` on Mac and `ifconfig eth0` on Linux will both produce human-readable output, but that output isn't in the same format. For example, here are output lines from a Mac and a Linux box:

```
inet 192.168.42.100 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.42.255
inet addr:192.168.99.35  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

You can parse both of these with something like:*

```
addr=$(ipconfig $iface inet | awk '/^\tinet / {print $2} | sed 's/addr://')
```

<sub>* Use `inet6` in place of `inet` both times for IPv6.</sub>

But I wouldn't guarantee that will work on every platform you care about.

Comment: I would like to use what I have for the 3 OSs I have mentioned. How do I differentiate it for Mac?

Comment: @user2921139: You mentioned 2 OSs if you count all the distros as Linux, and 4 OSs if you count them all as separate, so I'm not sure which 3 you mean.

Comment: What I am looking at is, an easy way to find if its a Mac/unix and find its IP.